# RViz does not show robot appearance (RViz tutorials: building from scratch)

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow examples from [URDF Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)

```
/opt/ros/melodic/share/urdf_tutorial$ roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=urdf/01-myfirst.urdf
... logging to /home/loic/.ros/log/e042da92-b408-11e8-943d-0800271f9a30/roslaunch-duneton-1649.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://duneton:36715/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: melodic
 * /rosversion: 1.14.3
 * /use_gui: True

NODES
  /
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [1668]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [1669]
process[rviz-3]: started with pid [1670]
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

But no cylinder appears in RViz.

I check with all examples of the tutorials. I have never surfaces, only axes (3 colors). Here with second example :
[image description http://ldayot.free.fr/CaptureDu2018-09-09_10-53-41.png](http://ldayot.free.fr/CaptureDu2018-09-09_10-53-41.png)

I attempted on raspbian or debian (in virtualbox) both on stretch with melodic.

Here result of rviz -l :

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/5f32cbe57cdf31fb4478b5e1ace8e038

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302787/rviz-does-not-show-robot-appearance-(rviz-tutorials:-building-from-scratch)/) by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you show us the output of `echo $LC_NUMERIC`?

---

Edit:

> Empty : $ echo $LC_NUMERIC

Can you do this in a terminal and then try RViz again (from the same terminal)?

```
export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
```

If this 'solves' it then please see [ros/urdfdom_headers#41](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/41) and [ros/urdfdom_headers#45](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/45).

You may need to add support for `en_US` to your locale configuration.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on 2018-09-09**:
Empty :
$ echo $LC_NUMERIC

**Comment by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on 2018-09-09**:
I had to reconfigure locales to add en_US.UTF-8. After export command, rviz displays surfaces. Thanks you.
What may I do to mark resolved the issue?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
Just turned my comment into a proper answer you can accept.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-09**:
Could you please make some noise (ie: post a comment) on [ros/urdfdom_headers#45](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/45)? The more people complain, the earlier we can get this fixed upstream.

Please include a link to this ROS Answers Q&A if you do.

Thanks.